# Session ID changes at every CORS POST despite credentials='include'

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, cors, fetch

I'd like to connect my front-end website via CORS to my backend API that uses simple authentication (name and password) to authorize users. To do this, I use Javascripts Fetch API. It appears that the session ID of each fetch call changes even though I use `credentials = "initial"`:

```
function onClick() {
  const url = 'https://localhost:44394/api/account/Login/Standard/P@$$w0rd';
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    mode: 'cors'
  }).then(function (response) {
      return response.text().then(function (text) {
      document.getElementById("at").innerHTML = text;
    });
  });
}
```

I have added the following to the `Configure()` of my `AspNetCore-Startup.cs`:

```
app.UseCors(builder=>builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowCredentials().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
```

And to `ConfigureServices()` of my `AspNetCore-Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddCors();
```

I cannot login with the `onClick()`-function. When I am using `credentials: "same-origin"` instead of `include` I can login but a following API call would change the session ID of the call.

How can I prevent the Fetch Call from changing the session ID?

**EDIT:**
In my account-controller I access the current session ID via `HttpContext.Session`. Maybe that's something like a server session and not the requester session?

Answer (score 1):

Session Cookies have nothing to do with CORS. CORS is about requests to other domains.

A session is "some data" stored on the server and identified by an ID stored as cookie in your browser.

- Session init: Server set cookie in browser (see response headers)
- Next requests: Browser sends cookie to server (so our server knows which data to use)

Knowing this, it's easy to debug the problem:

1. Your server must send the initial cookie. Is there a cookie in the response headers?
2. Can you see the cookie in your browser?
3. Does the client send this cookie with all requests?

You can see this in your browsers developer tools > network panel.

> Maybe that's something like a server session and not the requester session?

It's always and only the server session. Your browser simply tells the server which session (data) to use.

Your question does not provide details on what happens, so I have to guess: GDPR could prevent asp core from setting the session cookie.

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-2.2

```
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
        ...
    });
```

Could work as a "quick and dirty" solution.